# What is faster in PHP: dechex() or sprintf("%x")?

Tags: php, hex, printf

What is the fastest way to convert a number to the hexadecimal representation in PHP: `dechex($number)` or `sprintf("%x",$number)`?

Comment: I thought there should be some documentations about it. https://www.php.net/ says nothing.
Is it enough to use one script with cycles. Or should I generate many simultaneous requests?

Comment: A good performance test will generally run hundreds of tests, to ensure other factors (such as CPU load on the server, memory usage, network latency etc) which may fluctuate over time, don't undully affect the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...  `dechex` is faster, by an insignifficant number
0.0042848587036133
0.0037119388580322

```php
<?php

$numbers = [];

for ($i = 1; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $numbers[] = random_int(1, 10000);
}

$start = microtime(true);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $test = sprintf("%x",$number);
}

echo microtime(true) - $start . PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $test = dechex($number);
}

echo microtime(true) - $start . PHP_EOL;
```